# Autoincrement id in database

Tags: c#, sqlite, auto-increment

I have a table

```
    id int
    sub_id int
    name varchar
```

Example:

```
id, sub_id, name
1, 1, USA
1, 2, Germany 
1, 3, Russia
2, 1, English
2, 2, German
2, 3, Russian
```

Let's say user enter 3 for id, so `sub_id` should be 1, 2, 3... if user will enter 4, `sub_id` count should start from 1. Is it possible to autoincrement `sub_id`?

Comment: what is `sub_id`?  Does it act like a sequencer or is it a self reference: `German is spoken in Germany`?

Comment: SQL provides automatically incrementing fields, as in the marked duplicate. If you have some specific question about using that, please fix your question so that it explains clearly what you already know and what _specifically_ you're having trouble with. Also, if your question does not involve C# programming (it appears not to), then remove the [tag:c#] tag from your question. If it does involve C# programming, please explain how.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, that's a wrong match. OP is definitely not asking for `IDENTITY`. Looks like you misinterpreted the question. Voting to reopen it.

Comment: it is also tagged as SQLite not SqlServer

Comment: @PeterDuniho please read my post. I'm using c#, SQL, SQLite. Maybe it can be done through c#, that's why I tagged c#. Please open...

Comment: @PeterDuniho definitely not the same question as the duplicate you tagged!  This individual wants an second identity column that resets every x # of rows based on values on another row and column!

Comment: @axzufs iookup up the equivalent of ROW_NUMBER window functions for sqllite.  If you just want to generate on the fly you will be able to write the query.  If you want to store it in the database it will require an extra update statement based on the results.